# Translation of "trumped up charges"

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, passage-identification

There was a Greek play translated to Latin wherein a term was translated then to English as **"trumped up charges"**.

Might somebody know the play and more particularly the term itself?

Comment: Do you have any additional context? Like the subject of the play or something else? Latin *calumnia* in Roman law means a false accusation

Comment: No. I am afraid I don't

Comment: Guy! Calumnae was the word I was looking for.

Comment: Just posted it as an answer. Happy to help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the little information you give, all that can be said is *calumnia* (pl. *calumniae*) is Latin (specifically, Roman law) for false accusation.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 7):

I agree that [*calumnia*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=calumnia&la=la#lexicon) is a good translation for a "trumped-up charge." Here is one example from Cicero:

> condemnati erant Fabricii: nec elabi alio accusatore poterat Albius nec sine ignominia **calumniae** relinquere accusationem Cluentius ([Cic. Pro Cluentio, XXXI](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/cluentio.shtml))
>
> *the Fabricii had been condemned; Albius could not possibly escape if there were any other prosecutor, nor could Cluentius abandon the prosecution without rendering himself liable to the imputation of having **trumped up a false accusation**. (trans. C. D. Yonge)*

Here are a few other possible phrases that abound in Latin's wide judicial vocabulary:

### [*commenticius -a -um*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcommenticius)

> ille quo modo **crimen commenticium** confirmaret non inveniebat. ([Cic. S. Rosc. 15.42](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:phi,0474,002:15:42))
>
> *He did not find a way to support his **trumped-up charge**.*

This can also be used as a verb:

> **Commenta** mater **est** esse ex alio viro
>   Nescio quo puerum natum ([Ter. Ad. 4.5](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:abo:phi,0134,006:4:5))
>
> *The mother has **trumped up a tale**, that there is a child by some other man, I know not who (trans. Henry Thomas Riley)*

### *mendacium compositum*

> Ne tu istic hodie malo tuo **compositis mendaciis**
>   advenisti, audaciai columen, consutis dolis. ([Pl. Am. I.1](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0030%3Aact%3D1%3Ascene%3D1))
>
> *Assuredly, at your peril have you come here this day, with your **trumped-up lies**, your patched-up knaveries, you essence of effrontery. (trans. Henry Riley)*

### *fabula*

> oportuit autem, Perseu, si proditor ego patris regnique eram, si cum Romanis, si cum aliis inimicis patris inieram consilia, non expectatam **fabulam** esse noctis huius, sed proditionis [meae] ante me accusatum. ([Liv. 40 12](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0144%3Abook%3D40%3Achapter%3D12))
>
> *But, Perseus, if I were a traitor to my father and the realm, if I were scheming with the Romans or with any of my father's enemies, you ought not to have waited for this **trumped-up story** of last night's doings, you ought to have accused me of treachery before this. (trans. Canon Roberts)